# MLE of Variance of Normal Distribution Asymptotically Unbiased?

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, unbiased-estimator

So the MLE of the variance of a normal distribution, $\sigma^2$, is just the mean squared error, i.e., $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} (\hat{y_i} - y_i)^2$. Clearly, this goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

But MLE estimators are asymptotically unbiased, so what is going on here?

Comment: Why does that clearly go to zero? I ask, because it clearly does not go to zero.

Comment: Am I missing some $N$ term?

Comment: $\hat y_i$ should be $\overline{y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$ but that doesn't change much. You are diving a sum of $n$ nonzero elements by $n$. This does not necessarily go to zero. In fact, if the $n$ nonzero elements are bounded away from $\delta > 0$ with very high probability, then this will certainly not go to zero.

Comment: Do you have a source I can read for that? Ideally there should be a factor of $N$ to "cancel" out the $\frac{1}{N}$ like how it is for proving the unbiasedness of $\hat{\mu}$ right?

Comment: It is well known that for a normally distributed $Y$ that $E\left[\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(\overline{y} - y_i)^2 \right] = \sigma^2$ and thus $E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\overline{y} - y_i)^2 \right] = \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2$ which implies the MLE is asymptotically unbiased. Maybe see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction

Comment: The factor of n comes from the linearity of the expectation and the fact you are adding $n$ terms. This ends up cancelling the $1/n$. To make this especially easy to see, if the population mean $\mu$ is known and you replace $\hat y_i$ with $\mu$ in your formula then you are adding $n$ iid random variables. By linearity of the expectation, we get $$E \left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\mu-y_i)^2 \right] =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E \left[ (\mu-y_i)^2 \right] =\frac{1}{n} n  E \left[ (\mu-y_1)^2 \right] =  E \left[ (\mu-y_1)^2 \right] = \sigma^2.$$

Comment: So then if the expectation of MSE is $\sigma^2$, then why is it a biased estimator? I think I've gotten a bit confused with your last step there. The math seems to check out though, so there appears to be some conflicting logic on my end due to a missed step

Comment: I used the true $\mu$, which corresponds with the MLE when $\mu$ is known. Thus, if $\mu$ is known then the MLE is unbiased. When $\mu$ is estimated with $\overline{y}$ then there is a bias term. The bias is caused by double fitting/estimating. First you estimate the mean and then you plug the estimated mean into the variance formula. This gives a bias. Interestingly, if you obtain $\overline{y}$ from a different independent dataset then there is no bias (this is called sample-splitting). Disregard this last sentence, if it confuses you.

Comment: Oh interesting. I'd like to read more about sample-splitting, perhaps could you link me a proof for it or just how it applies in terms of CV or test/training sets?

Comment: The sample splitting comment might not be quite correct. I do believe you get a different bias because $\overline{y}$ is independent of the observations in the sum. But, it may not be zero. I added an answer below for the MLE case.

Comment: Hmm yeah that would make sense; you'd get different squared errors if you fix $y_i$ but allow $\hat{y}$ to vary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E \sum_{i=1}^n \left[\overline{Y} - Y_i\right]^2 =  E \sum_{i=1}^n \left[\overline{Y} - \mu + \mu - Y_i\right]^2 $$
$$=  \sum_{i=1}^n E [\overline{Y} - \mu]^2 + E[Y-\mu]^2 - 2E[(\overline{Y}-\mu)(Y_i-\mu)]$$
where $\overline{Y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$.
Note,
$$E[\overline{Y}-\mu]^2 = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n E[(Y_i-\mu) (Y_j - \mu)] = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n  E[(Y_i-\mu)^2] = \sigma^2/n, $$
since $Y_i-\mu$ and $Y_j-\mu$ are mean zero and independent if $i \neq j$.

Thus,
$$E \sum_{i=1}^n \left[\overline{Y} - Y_i\right]^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \sigma^2/n + \sigma^2 - 2E[(\overline{Y}-\mu)(Y_i-\mu)] \right\}.$$

Next, note
$$E[(\overline{Y}-\mu)(Y_i-\mu)] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n E[(Y_j-\mu)(Y_i-\mu)] =   E[(Y_i-\mu)(Y_i-\mu)]/n = \sigma^2/n.$$

Thus,
$$E \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left[\overline{Y} - Y_i\right]^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \sigma^2/n + \sigma^2 - 2\sigma^2/n \right\} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left\{  \sigma^2 - \sigma^2/n \right\} = \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2.$$

Comment: Many thanks! This was very useful!